# Oracle 12c - column default string value for record not inserted - null instead

Tags: database, oracle, default-value

I am facing the very interesting intermitted issue and I don't know what can cause this issue. I have one database table and there is set DEFAULT value for one column (string value - i.e. "A").

Records are inserted automatically with scheduler job and I looked at the history and once there was inserted "null" instead of "A" value - only for one record. Other records were inserted correctly.

(note: there were thousands of records inserted and only one had null)

Do anybody know what can cause this intermittent issue and why there is null instead of DEFAULT value which is defined for this particular column?

If you need some example of the table definition, let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Yes - you should definitely share the DDL to create the table as well as the `INSERT` statement used by the scheduler job.

Answer (score 1):

`DEFAULT` values are only used when a column is not referenced in an insert statement. If a column is referenced and is nullable then it can be set to null.

With 12c you have the option to change this behavior by using `DEFAULT ON NULL` instead of just `DEFAULT`.

Reference: [DEFAULT Values On Explicit NULLs](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/default-values-for-table-columns-enhancements-12cr1#nulls)